# How to handle onclick event of a dynamically created grid view in android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

in my android app, i have created 3 grid views dynamically.Hear is the code.and it displayed 3 grid views.

```
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
                LinearLayout inflatedView =  (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.library_gallery, null);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 300);
                inflatedView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                mGridView = (GridView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.library_gallary);
                if(Thambs!=null){
                    mGridView.setAdapter(new LibraryGalleryAdapter(mContext,Thambs1));
                    setResourse(i,Names,values1);
                }
      }
```

Now i want to uniquely identify the click events of these 3 dynamically created grid views.
Any idea please?

**EDIT:**

```
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v,final int posision, long id) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "id : "+v.getId());
}
```

but it will return same id for each grid view onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gridView.setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). In the click listener, `use parent.getId` to find the id of the parent. If you have multiple grid views, you should call `gridView.setId()` to set it to something unique.

Answer (score 0):

try using view.getId() inside onItemclick().

Comment: view.getId() will return same id for every grid view.

Answer (score 0):

For each `mGridView` you need a separate `View.onClickListener` interface implementation, or a single `View.onClickListener` implementation and distinguishing each grid with `View.getId()` (as *vishwa* points out). It depends on what you want to do with each grid, and how you want them to behave.

Comment: where is the place i implement the View.onClickListener ?you mean inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to implement onItemclickListener interface in your class , then you need to check that clicked item is from which grid view by getting Id by  view.getId() of clicked view by second argument in onItemClickListener.

then you can identify which view is clicked check that clicked view is childview of GridView by using first argument from OnItemclicked() i.e. parent, check that this parent is which gridview then perform action accordingly for that View.

Hope this explanation works for you..